# increase width of element by adding class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you increase width of element in Bootstrap 3 by simply adding class to it?

given the `width` in classes like `.col-lg-` are not defined in %age terms, the width of the preceeding element prevents the addition to increase width predictably.

Has Bootstrap 3 provided any alternative?

Elements like input boxes. `input(type='text')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Input Boxes specifically [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545309/width-of-text-input-fields-in-bootstrap3?rq=1). using `.input-lg-` height can be altered but there does not seem to be an alternative for width. [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) advises use of class `form-control` in input boxes which sets width to 100%. You can add separately width to be more specific.

for [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) the classes are defined which determine the width.